# border Is moving div while it appears

Tags: css, flexbox

Well the code is

```css
.all-card{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.left-panel-child{
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    border:white solid;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 0.1px 0 0 0;
}

.left-panel-child:hover{
    border-left:white solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-card">
    <div class="left-panel">
        <div class="left-panel-child"><span>hello</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that the left border that appears after`: hover' moves the text away from itself

I ve tried `position:absolute` with `relative`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a transparent border to the initial element

```css
.all-card{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.left-panel-child{
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    border:white solid;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 0.1px 0 0 0;
    border-left:transparent solid;
}

.left-panel-child:hover{
    border-left:white solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-card">
    <div class="left-panel">
        <div class="left-panel-child"><span>hello</span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

is causing by the white border when mouse is on the `div` because you're turning the `div`'s border to white which is the same color as the background one means that the border will look like is pushing somehow but not just remove `border-left:white solid;` or change the color to see the difference

```css
.all-card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.left-panel-child {
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  border: solid white;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 0.1px 0 0 0;
}

.left-panel-child:hover {
  /*border-left:white solid;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="all-card">
  <div class="left-panel">
    <div class="left-panel-child"><span>hello</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```